# parsing of seconds and millisecond using python

Tags: python

I have time stamp in format of "10:24:00.744" I want to fetch the seconds value (here -- 00) and millisecond value (here -- 744) in different variables using python. Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: what you have tried so far . . simply posting the question and asking for answer won't help you.

Comment: Sure, Thanks. will keep that in mind while asking next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to parse the time, and then get the seconds and milliseconds from it -

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> h = datetime.strptime('10:24:00.744','%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> seconds = h.second
>>> milliseconds = h.microsecond/1000
>>> print(seconds)
0
>>> print(milliseconds)
744.0
```

`strptime()` function is used to parse datetime from string, the directives mean -

> %H - Hour
>
> %M - Minutes
>
> %S - Seconds
>
> %f - Microseconds

More details about support directives can be [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Can the downvoter please comment why this is a bad solution?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you please advice why you think this is a bad answer ? And how I can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
a = "10:24:00.744"
seconds = a[6:8]
milliseconds = a[9:]
print "Seconds", seconds
print "Milliseconds", milliseconds
```

You will get the following output:

```
Seconds '00'
Milliseconds '744'
```